# return a 302 from AWS API Gateway using request path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple site running on Lambda, using a single proxy resource in API Gateway to route requests to it.

I'm trying to set up some "vanity URLs": someone arriving on `/somepath` should be redirected to `/?source=somepath`.

I'm trying to achieve this in API Gateway rather than passing it through to the Lambda app to manage.

- I've set up a resource on `/somepath`, with a Mock integration type.
- The Method Response contains only a 302 type, which contains a `Location` response header.
- The Integration Response contains a corresponding 302 response type
- The Header Mappings contain a `Location` header mapped to `context.resourcePath`

This works, sort of. A request to `/somepath` returns a 302 response with a Location header value of `/somepath`.

But how can I format that Header Mapping value to be (i.e.):

`/?source=${context.resourcePath}`

Is there a way I can do this all in API Gateway, using only a Mock endpoint instead of passing the request through to an actual integration backend to return a header value?